# Computing for the value of the last column cell -- involves dynamic table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

**Consider the following HTML table:**

```
<table id="myTable1">
    <tr id="TR1">
        <td><input type="text" id="quantity1" name="quantity1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="weight1" name="weight1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="sub_total1" name="sub_total1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What i'm trying to accomplish here is that I need to update the value for the **sub_total** field **on every row** based on the values typed in the **quantity** and **weight** fields **on the same row** every time **keyup()** is triggered.

Now I believe this would be a much manageable task if the table I'm working on is static only. But the inclusion of the dynamic adding of table rows caused me troubles.

---

**JQuery for dynamic addition of rows:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function() {

    $('#myTable1 tr:last').after(
        '<tr id="TR"><td><input type="text" name="quantity' + counter + 
            '" id="quantity' + counter + '" value=""></input></td>' +

        '<td><input type="text" name="weight' + counter + 
            '" id="weight' + counter + '" value=""></input></td>' +

        '<td><input type="text" name="sub_total' + counter + 
            '" id="sub_total' + counter + '" value=""></input></td></tr>'
    );

    counter++;
});
});
```

---

**Here we have the formula to be used in computing for the sub_total**:

```
var sub_total  = ((170 * first 10 kilos) + (70 * the remaining weight)) * (quantity);
```

**So given the sample values:
quantity = 10
weight = 15**, we should have

```
var sub_total  = ((170 * 10) + (70 * 5)) * (10);
```

---

**I have the following as a start but ' not quite sure what to place inside these functions**

```
$('#myTable1 input[id^=\'quantity\'], #myTable1 input[id^=\'weight\']').live('keyup',function() {

    $('#myTable1 input[id^=\'quantity\'], #myTable1 input[id^=\'weight\']').each(function(index, value) {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to match the parent table row of the modified element. From there, it's easier to locate the `quantity`, `weight` and `sub_total` elements:

```
$("#myTable1 [id^=quantity], #myTable1 [id^=weight]").live("keyup", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var quantity = parseInt($("[id^=quantity]", $tr).val());
    var weight = parseInt($("[id^=weight]", $tr).val());

    var firstTen;
    if (weight <= 10) {
        firstTen = weight;
        weight = 0;
    } else {
        firstTen = 10;
        weight -= 10;
    }

    $("[id^=sub_total]", $tr).val((170 * firstTen + 70 * weight) * quantity);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frédéric the solution you have provided worked! I was not familiar with __closest()__ prior to this -- now that's one more function added to my jQuery toolbox!

Answer (score 0):

```
var input_cols = $(
    '<tr id="TR"><td><input type="text" name="quantity' + counter + 
        '" id="quantity' + counter + '" value=""></input></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" name="weight' + counter + 
        '" id="weight' + counter + '" value=""></input></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" name="sub_total' + counter + 
        '" id="sub_total' + counter + '" value=""></input></td></tr>'
).find('input[name=quantity], input[name=weight]').keyup(function() { updateTotal(this); });

$('#myTable1 tr:last').after(input_cols);

function updateTotal(el) {
  el = el.closest('tr');
  weight = el.find('input[name=weight]').val();
  quantity = el.find('input[name=quantity]').val();
  el.find('input[name=sub_total]').val( quantiy * weight .... put your formula here);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is : nothing happening for the dynamic fields it is obvious that the keyup event is not bound.

Bind the event using .bind() or call the to do on keyup inside the dynamically generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Give different class name for different input field such as `quantity` `weight` `sub_total`
and try this

```
    $("#addButton").click(function() {

          $('#myTable1 tr:last').after(
          '<tr id="TR' + counter +'"><td><input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity' + counter +
            '" id="quantity' + counter + '" value=""></input></td>' +

            '<td><input type="text" class="weight" name="weight' + counter +
            '" id="weight' + counter + '" value=""></input></td>' +

            '<td><input type="text" class="sub_total" name="sub_total' + counter +
            '" id="sub_total' + counter + '" value=""></input></td></tr>'
        );

          counter++;
          $('tr').each(function(){
            var qnty = 0
            var weight = 0;
            $('input.quantity', $(this)).keyup(function(){
              qnty = Number($(this).val());
              if(qnty != 0 && weight != 0){
                newRowCalculation($(this).parent().parent('tr'), qnty, weight);
              }

            });
            $('input.weight', $(this)).keyup(function(){
              weight = Number($(this).val());
              if(qnty != 0 && weight != 0){
                newRowCalculation($(this).parent().parent('tr'), qnty, weight);
              }
            });                        
          });

function newRowCalculation(elem, qnty, weight){
        if(weight > 10){
          var extraWeight = Number(weight - 10);
          var subTotal = (170 * 10 + 70 * extraWeight) * qnty;
          $('.sub_total', $(elem)).val(subTotal);
        }
        else{
          var subTotal = (170 * weight) * qnty;
          $('.sub_total', $(elem)).val(subTotal);
        }

      }
```